# NaN Values when selecting specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Currently trying to gather some knowledge regarding Data Science with Pandas and Matplotlib.

**what I want to do**
Select Neighbourhood Groups with corresponding Price for renting Private Rooms (AirBnB)

**The Problem**
I get for one column the correct data, but for the remaining I receive NaN Values. Appreciating any help, below you can find a code snippet and the output.

```
    ap_df = pd.DataFrame()

for neighbourhood_group in df['neighbourhood_group'].unique():
    nbhg_df = df.copy()[df['neighbourhood_group']==neighbourhood_group]
    nbhg_df[f"{neighbourhood_group}_Price"] = nbhg_df['price']
    nbhg_df.set_index("id", inplace=True)
    nbhg_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    if ap_df.empty:
        ap_df = nbhg_df[[f"{neighbourhood_group}_Price"]]
    else:
        ap_df = ap_df.join(nbhg_df[f"{neighbourhood_group}_Price"])

ap_df
```

[Output I receive after performing the above Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8QPR.png)

Comment: It seems like the join is failing, can you give us an idea of what `nbhg_df` and `ap_df` looks like?

Comment: We need to see the data format to help you

Comment: @CeliusStingher [link]https://imgur.com/a/bielQFJ those are the outputs of both nbhg_df and ap_df. I tried to create a DataFrame with every Neighbourhood Group and gather the corresponding price inside a for loop, not sure why the join isn't working, on another project the exact same algorithm works :/

Comment: @KostasCharitidis https://imgur.com/Dfj7oPc the Informations I could gather through the info() Method of the original Data Frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I can help you with another simpler and working example that fits your needs

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'cat': ['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3'],
    'price': [1, 2, 3]
})

df.set_index(df['id'], drop=True, inplace=True)
new_df = pandas.DataFrame(index=df.index)

for var in df['cat'].unique():
    new_df[f'{var}_price'] = df[df['cat'] == var]['price']


new_df
```

Output :

```
    cat_1_price   cat_2_price   cat_3_price
id          
1    1.0             NaN             NaN
2    NaN             2.0             NaN
3    NaN             NaN             3.0
```

Comment: This definetly helped me alot :) thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome :) but please next time try to be more explicit on SOF questions so that you could have an answer from most of the viewers